# How to cycle a condition through a set of arrays to return the values of the one that is true

Tags: php, arrays, foreach, conditional-statements

I have a textarea that submits text which is converted to an array using the explode function, then the values of that array is made into individual arrays within a foreach loop. This is the function

**The text area entry**
    mon|0000|0500|The Morning Blast|sally.jpg|DJ Sally
    ---
    mon|0500|1000|Day Time Soap|wally.jpg|Wally

**The processing code**

```
$itemlist = trim(preg_replace('/\n/', '', $itemlist ));
$itemlist = explode('---', $itemlist);

$dow = strtolower(date( 'D' ));
$tod = date( 'Hi' );

foreach($itemlist as $items) {
//this creates 2 arrays with 6 keys each
//array([0]=>mon[1]=>0000[2]=>0500[3]=>The Morning Blast[4]=>sally.jpg[5]=>DJ Sally)
//array([0]=>mon[1]=>0500[2]=>1000[3]=>Day Time Soap[4]=>wally.jpg[5]=>Wally)

$itempart = explode('|', $items);

if($itempart[0] == $dow && $tod >= $itempart[1] && $tod <= $itempart[2] ) {
?>

<div>
<h4><?php echo $itempart[3]; ?></h4>
<p><?php echo $itempart[5]; ?></p>
<img src="<?php echo $itempart[4]; ?>" />
</div>

<?php } 
}//endforeach ?>
```

**The problems**
The condition which checks the day of week and time of day, processes only the first array and correctly returns the output HTML, but once the time expires and it is then false, the subsequent array is not processed even though it is true.

The logic seems correct but it just won't work. What is needed to make this scan the list of arrays and return only the one that is true?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That code is not complete: the loop is opened but never finished. Your problem is you're only trimming \n while you also have to expect other characters (**carriage return**, not only **line feed**). Either correctly eliminate line breaks

```
$itemlist= trim( preg_replace( '/\\s*[\\n\\r]\\s*/', '', $itemlist ) );
```

or trim it later with

```
$itempart= explode( '|', trim( $items ) );
```

otherwise your condition fails, because `fri` in your array element is prepended by a **carriage return**.

Comment: The loop in my script is closed. I simply neglected it in the question.